# Webpack dev server not always serving index.html

Tags: webpack

I have

```js
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const webpack = require("webpack");
module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: "bundle.js",
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "index.html",
        }),
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/i,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                include: [path.resolve(__dirname, "src")],
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "postcss-loader"],
            },
        ],
    },
    devServer: {
        static: {
            directory: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
        },
        historyApiFallback: {
            index: "index.html",
        },
    },
};
```

And in my `index.html` there is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>Joyride</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

in my `webpack.config.js` file and it works great for routes that are one-deep, but for anything two deep (ie https://localhost:8080/foo/bar) it 404s with: **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)**.

I'm wondering if there's another setting I can use to get it to always find & serve up `bundle.js`? Thanks!

Comment: Don't think it's a Webpack issue. Must be the router. Greate if you share the routing snippet

Comment: I'm using the `HtmlWebpackPlugin` and my HTML is `<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="utf-8" /><title>test</title></head><body></body></html>`. I haven't done any routing with it yet. I think that the only steps going on are that the HTML plugin emits some HTML and automatically adds `bundle.js` in it, but then the browser can't find `bundle.js` from the dev server. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Update post with the required details and webpack config. As your question is regarding routing if you are having any routing config do share it in the original post.